# What is the ideal way to unfreeze a tag based Chat Room?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

This question relates to the frozen [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room, a user friendly room for discussing Selenium features, functionality, usage and implementation.

The mentioned chatroom had been frozen and new messages cannot be added. The last message was was posted 265 days ago.

I'm aware I can create a new room at any point of time. Still I would like to know if there is a proper procedure to request to unfreeze a frozen chatroom.

Comment: _You should flag either the post the room was created on (if any), or raise a custom flag in chat._: The room wasn't created based on any post. It was a user room created by me. So no post such to raise a custom flag. Even _custom flags_ are frozen within the chatroom.

Comment: @DebanjanB Just raise a mod flag on any of your posts and provide all the needed information (link to room, reason to unfreeze etc.), the fact that the post you're flagging isn't relevant to the room doesn't matter.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I needed that guidance but haven't found/seen any proper guidance on _How to?_

Comment: Well... that's because there isn't really any proper guidance on it, it's not something that generally needs to be done, I've updated the answer on the proposed duplicate to indicate that any of your own posts will do as well, but really... it doesn't matter what post it is at all. Flag any post you like, as long as your flag is clear and contains everything needed the mod will understand what you're asking. They can after all read :p

Comment: @Nick I strongly feel the info you provided must be documented somewhere so anyone having the same requirement in the future can be directed to. Thanks for the pointer.